# Datasource Configuration Wizard do not show colum from stored procedure source

Tags: c#, datasource, reportviewer, wizard

Is this bugs or need something to be done first, I have tried both with VS 2010 and VS 2013 update 2

I Want to create report (Microsoft Reporting View-local) which the source data are from stored procedure, something like :

```
Create Procedure One_ok
as
    Select * From MyTable
```

this one is OK Datasource configuration wizard successfully return the column from the stored procedure.

```
Create Procedure One_Not_ok
as
    Select * Into #result From MyTable
    Select * from #result
```

This one Datasource configuration wizard can not return the column from the stored procedure, when click the tree expand simple blank

Any help please ? It's a really bad news if must declare the dataset manually

Thx
sen

Answer (score 0):

ok I have found alternative quite way, create report-BI project file ext will rdl after done all things copy it to new file rdlc.

why Microsoft do not improve configuration wiz to query designer like ones in report-BI

any other easy ways for best practice without manually copy from rdl to rdlc ?